# Null object reference when calling a sub in parent class via a user control

Tags: ajax, vb.net, user-controls

I have a user control containing a LinkButton that, when clicked, calls a sub in the parent class. The sub is being called OK when I click the LinkButton, but the objects referenced within that sub are all triggering null object reference errors. What am I doing wrong?

To keep things as short as possible, I am showing only the relevant subs inside their classes.

Here is the **LinkClick** sub of the user control:

```
Public Class Dashboard
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

        ...(Other code here)...

        Private Sub LinkClick(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)

            Dim action = e.CommandArgument
            Dim cls As New MainPage
            cls.Dashboard_Clicked(action)

        End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the parent class with the sub being called via LinkClick:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class MainPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    ...(Other code here)...

    Public Sub Dashboard_Clicked(action)

        mpe.Show()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the markup on the parent control, which shows the markup for the user control and the markup for the object I am unsuccessfully trying to reference in the sub:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TSEnterHours.ascx.vb"
Inherits="App.MainPage" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Src="Dashboard.ascx" TagName="Dashboard" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<uc:Dashboard SourceProcName="Dashboard.QueryName" runat="server">
    <DashboardParameters>
        <dashboardparameter name="aID" useenvironmentvalue="aID" />
    </DashboardParameters>
    <Items>
        <item type="hyperlink" Action="PTO_Clicked" label="YTD PTO Taken" field="TotalPTO" />
    </Items>
</uc:Dashboard>

<!-- Other code... -->

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnDummy" PopupControlID="PTOPanel"
BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" OkControlID="btnDummy" CancelControlID="btnDummy"
BehaviorID="mpeBehavior_PTO" />
```

By the way, the "parent" class is, itself, a user control operating inside a tab container. I don't think that makes a difference but thought I should mention it just in case.

Comment: Try getting the user controls actual parent page instead of creating a new (Dim cls As New MainPage). Try this: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-Parent-Page-method-from-Child-Usercontrol-using-Reflection-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As WozzeC has stated, newing MainPage means its associated with a Dashboard instance, not its parent.

I'm not too hot on web stuff at the moment but I'd say that MainPage contains a Dashboard. If this is the case, a better design would be to give Dashboard a reference to MainPage and then use that reference to call the Dashboard_Clicked() method.

Or maybe get Dashboard to raise an event that MainPage can listen to?